# Select2 dropdown issue. How do i populate a date from datepicker into a select2 dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, bootstrap-datepicker

I am running Select2 version 3.5.3. I am having trouble appending a date to the select2 input control after selecting a date. What is the correct way of achieving this given that i am creating these inputs dynamically? To better explain what im doing, i have two inputs with datepickers attached to them. Additionally, i also have them as a select2. I initialize my select2 with a hard coded object. Everytime i select the option `calendar` from the dropdown the datepicker opens and lets me select a date. Once i have a date, i am trying to get the date as a string and append it to the same dropdown. When i do this, i can confirm that the string date is a valid string. I have no idea how to append this string to the select2 as i have about 50 tabs opened and the select2 documentation. Therefore, i hope someone can provide clarity as to why its not appending the new option and value. `$input2` is the same as `$input` but i have not developed any further due to problem described.

```
const dateRangeFilterOptions = [
                {id: "@calendar", text: "Calendar"},
                { id: "@thisDay", text: "Today" },
                { id: "@thisDay-1", text: "Yesterday" },
                { id: "@thisDay-7,@thisDay", text: "Last 7 days"  },
                { id: "@thisDay-14,@thisDay", text: "Last 14 days" },
                { id: "@thisMonth", text: "This month" },
                { id: "@thisDay-30,@thisDay", text: "Last 30 days" },
                { id: "@thisDay-60,@thisDay", text: "Last 60 days" }
            ]; 
            $input.addClass("datePicker dateFilter");
            const datepickerOptions: DatepickerOptions = {
                clearBtn: true,
                todayHighlight: true,
            };
            $input.datepicker(datepickerOptions);
            const $input2: JQuery = $("<input type='text'>")
                .attr("id", addlFilter.FilterId)
                .attr("data-id", `${addlFilter.FilterId}End`)
                .addClass(
                    `form-control input-sm datePicker dateFilter addlFilter2 ${addlFilter.QueueKeys.join(" ")}`);
            $input2.datepicker(datepickerOptions);
            const $row: JQuery = $("<div class='row'></div>");
            const $colMd6: JQuery = $("<div class='col-md-6' style='padding-right:2px'></div>");
            const $2colMd6: JQuery = $("<div class='col-md-6' style='padding-left:2px'></div>");

            $input.prop("placeholder", "Start Date");
            $input2.prop("placeholder", "End Date");
            $input.appendTo($colMd6);
            $input2.appendTo($2colMd6);
            $colMd6.appendTo($row);
            $2colMd6.appendTo($row);
            $row.appendTo($formGroup);
            var dateSelected = "";

            $input.select2({
                placeholder: "Select a date",
                multiple: false,
                minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
                data: dateRangeFilterOptions
            }).on("change", function (e) {
                var el = $(this);
                if (el.val() === "@calendar") {
                    $input.datepicker("show");
                    $input.datepicker()
                        .on('changeDate', function (date: any) {
                            if (date.date.toString() === "") {
                                dateSelected = "";
                            } else {
                                dateSelected = date.date.toString();
                                var newOption = new Option(dateSelected, "@calendarDate", false, false);
                                $input.append(newOption).trigger('change');
                            }
                        });
                }

                });

            $input2.select2({
                placeholder: "Select a date",
                multiple: false,
                minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
                data: dateRangeFilterOptions
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different things, it turns out that for versions < 4.00  the way to update a select2 is to update its data: property. In my case it was the array of objects. Doing this will append a new option and value to the select2 dropdown.